# How can I remove a key from a dictionary?

Tags: julia

I want to remove a key-value pair from a dictionary.

I am creating a new dictionary for now:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two")
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"

julia> dict = Dict(k => v for (k, v) in dict if k != 2)
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "one"
```

But I want to update the existing dictionary instead. How can I do this in Julia?

Answer (score 21):

[`delete!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.delete!) will remove a key-value pair from a dictionary if the key exists, and have no effect if the key does not exist. It returns a reference to the dictionary:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two")
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  2 => "two"
  1 => "one"

julia> delete!(dict, 1)
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  2 => "two"
```

Use [`pop!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.pop!-Tuple%7BAny,Any,Any%7D) if you need to use the value associated with the key. However, it will error if the key does not exist:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two");

julia> value = pop!(dict, 2)
"two"

julia> dict
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "one"

julia> value = pop!(dict, 2)
ERROR: KeyError: key 2 not found
```

You can avoid throwing an error with the three argument version of `pop!`. The third argument is a default value to return in case the key does not exist:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two");

julia> value_or_default = pop!(dict, 2, nothing)
"two"

julia> dict
Dict{Int64,String} with 1 entry:
  1 => "one"

julia> value_or_default = pop!(dict, 2, nothing)
```

Use [`filter!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.filter!) to bulk remove key-value pairs according to some predicate function:

```
julia> dict = Dict(1 => "one", 2 => "two", 3 => "three", 4 => "four");

julia> filter!(p -> iseven(p.first), dict)
Dict{Int64,String} with 2 entries:
  4 => "four"
  2 => "two"
```